# Android Newbie - Can't extract token from the server response

Tags: java, android

I run this code :

```
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.get(get_token, new HttpResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(String responseBody) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        llHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                token = responseBody;

            }
```

And the responseBody gives me back :

```
{"response":{"token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJhdXRob3JpemF0aW9uRmlJ9","status":"success"}}
```

How do I get "token" as a string , same for "status"

Comment: Use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code.

```
   protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.get(get_token, new HttpResponseCallback() {
            @Override 
            public void success(String responseBody) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override 
                    public void run() { 

                        llHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                        String token = jObject.getString("token");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    } 
                }); 
            }
```

for more info look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606629/3998402)